# In Dart how to setInnerHtml elements with <template> tag?

Tags: dart, polymer

For example, I have a piece of code like this:

```
String_test="
<template>
<label> {{count2}}  SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS </label> 
<input id="input1" type='text' value='{{count2}}'>
</template>"
```

and I want to assign String_test to another element, like:

```
DivElement span2 = new Element.tag("div");
span2.setInnerHtml(String_test);
_content.nodes.add(span2);
```

However, the "< template >' tag is not recognized, nothing will show up.

NOTE: My purpose is to use  setInnerHtml to dynamically add contents to the webpage with data-binding still OK.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are including raw html in your Dart program files.  This is not how Dart works.  Dart has code (kept in .dart files) that is referenced to via a  tag in the HTML file. This very quick tutorial will show you how to do that: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/connect-dart-html/

Templating is found in the Dart Polymer library.  It is too long of a process to go into here but you can find a short tutorial at: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/

I would also mention that Angular comes in a Dart flavor and I find it more accessible than the Polymer libraries.  The tutorials and documentation are also much better.  Angular is a more comprehensive suite of libraries and it's tutorials can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki

Comment: Thanks for reply. My problem is that, sometimes I need to add or remove elements from the HTML. In this process, I still want to bind the elements to some models.

Comment: I think you will find Angular Directives or Polymer Templates make this relatively easy but the mindset is very different from traditional js/jquery.  Perhaps, rephrasing your question might help the community better answer it.